# Multiple if conditions pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking to write an if statement which does a calculation based on if 3 conditions across other columns in a dataframe are true. I have tried the below code which seems to have worked for others on stackoverflow but kicks up an error for me. Note the 'check', 'sqm' and 'sqft' columns are in float64 format.

```
if ((merge['check'] == 1) & (merge['sqft'] > 0) & (merge['sqm'] == 0)):
         merge['checksqm'] == merge['sqft']/10.7639
```

#Error below:

```
alueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-383-e84717fde2c0> in <module>
----> 1 if ((merge['check'] == 1) & (merge['sqft'] > 0) & (merge['sqm'] == 0)):
      2          merge['checksqm'] == merge['sqft']/10.7639

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1327 
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1329         raise ValueError(
   1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: That isn't the code you're running

Comment: It's right here: `----> 1 if merge[merge['check'] == 1] & ((merge['sqft'] > 0) & (merge['sqm'] == 0)):
      2          merge['checksqm'] == merge['sqft']/10.7639` Notice the missing brackets on the first check

Comment: sorry pasted the wrong error, have amended

Comment: @roganjosh just tried and get this:```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`pandas.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), which IIRC is more performant than doing it this way, and allows passing of an arbitrarily complex query string for selection. These query strings can also be made on the fly i.e. dynamically if so desired. See also [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval).

Comment: No, the errors are totally different and the new one is easily searchable

Comment: They don't need to look for more efficient approaches @jrbergen, they need to fix a logical error. They're asking if `[1, 2, 3]` is equal to `[1, 4, 3]`. Well, no, it's not but two of the three elements are. Pandas is asking how the user wants to handle that

Comment: That expression results in a series and a simple python if statement isn't sufficient to evaluate that result since you need to apply the if condition on each element of the series.

Comment: @cs95, I wrapped it in a function and used .apply() to do per your comment, but still get the following error and cannot seem to solve despite code looking like other solutions: ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'```


Function:

```def checksize(df):
   (1) if df[df['check'] == 1] & ((df['sqft'] > 0) & (df['sqm'] == 0)):
        (2)df['checksqm'] == df['sqft']/10.7639
        
(3)merge.apply(lambda row : checksize(merge), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each condition you code evaluates into a series of multiple boolean values.  The combined result of the 3 conditions also become a boolean series.  Python `if` statement cannot handle such Pandas series with evaluating each element in the series and feed to the statement following it one by one.  Hence, the error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

To solve the problem, you have to code it using Pandas syntax, like the following:

```
mask = (merge['check'] == 1) & (merge['sqft'] > 0) & (merge['sqm'] == 0)
merge.loc[mask, 'checksqm'] = merge['sqft']/10.7639
```

or, combine in one statement, as follows:

```
merge.loc[(merge['check'] == 1) & (merge['sqft'] > 0) & (merge['sqm'] == 0), 'checksqm'] = merge['sqft']/10.7639
```

In this way, Pandas can evaluate the boolean series and work on the rows corresponding to `True` values of the combined 3 conditions and process each row one by one taking corresponding values from each row for processing.  This kind of vectorized operation under the scene is not supported by ordinary Python statement such as `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `pd.Series` as the condition inside the `if` clause. This series is a mask of `True`, `False` values. You need to cast the series to `bool` using `series.any()` or `series.all()`.